# How to install a url encoder library on android?

Tags: java, android, url, encode, lib

Im trying to make a url encoder app. I tried to use java.net.urlencoder but I cant find its buildr, direct importing doest work for me also same problem from httpclient.
Can you give some working gradle/maven about java.net or http client

Comment: How come? `java.net.URLEncoder` is part of the JDK since the very beginning of Java and Android. How are you trying to import it?

Comment: java.net.URLEncoder But i cannot resolve to a type?